# How do I do summation of values in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

For example, I have the below parameters:

n = 3
i = day i

I wanted to do a summation (∑) of i to i-n of values of ID... so the first few days would be empty, but on the 7th day (with the value of 7), the code should add up values of 7,6,5,4 = 22

Help is much appreciated.

Sample code as below

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
df1$Date <- seq(as.Date("2023-12-21"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
```

Comment: Summing `ID`'s is a rare task. If `n = 3` why we start at day 7? `zoo::rollsumr(df1$ID, k = 4L, fill = NA)` and overwriting the first values might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, toting up ID's is a rare task.
Given your example for the 7th day, the window of the rolling sum should be `k = 4L`. `{zoo}` offers rolling functions:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
df1$Date <- seq(as.Date("2023-12-21"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
zoo::rollsumr(df1$ID, k = 4L, fill = NA)
#>  [1] NA NA NA 10 14 18 22 26 30 34
```

One of several ways to overwrite the first 6 values with `NA`'s:

```r
df1$rsum = zoo::rollsumr(df1$ID, k = 4L, fill = NA)
df1$rsum[1L:6L] = NA
df1$rsum
#>  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA 22 26 30 34
```

Constant difference of 4. If your `ID`'s are the sequence of natural numbers from 1 till some integer without gaps or duplication, simpler approaches can be used.

Or we write a small wrapper, which should be sufficiently fast for small to medium sized data sets:

```r
c_rollsumr = \(x, k, NAuntil) {  
  if(missing(NAuntil)) NAuntil = k 
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x), is.integer(k))
  res = rep(NA, length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) 
    if (i > k) res[i] = sum( x[(i-k+1L):i] )
  res[k:NAuntil] = NA 
  return(res) 
}
```

If you want to use it, make sure to add some checks. I haven't tested the wrapper intensively.

```r
> c_rollsumr(df1$ID, k = 4L, NAuntil = 6L)
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA 22 26 30 34
```

Comment: Please remove the line referencing the reprex package. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386875/answers-crediting-the-r-reprex-package

Comment: @AkselA This doesn't sound mandatory.